Label equation terms and reference them with \eqref{...}
I have a LaTeX equation like
$\varphi=f(g(...), h(...))$

I would like to give a label or a name name to g(...) and h(...) and reference them in the text with \eqref{...}.
The question is similar to Label terms of LaTeX equation and How do I put big brackets under different parts of an equation to attach text labels?, but I want to be able to references the terms in text afterwards.
Ideally, I want the equation to fit in a single row.
For instance, it would be nice if I can put labels on overbraces, so
that the output looks  something like:
$\varphi=f(\overbrace{g(...)}^{(1)}, \overbrace{h(...)}^{(2)})$

and then reference them in the text as (1) and (2) using \eqref.
It seems to me this is not possible, so I would appreciate also alternative solutions that do not look exactly like that, but that do not take too much space.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your notation for $\varphi=f(g(...), h(...))$ creates the impression that it's not a displayed equation but an inline piece of math. Is this impression correct? If it's not, what does $\varphi=f(g(...), h(...))$ denote? A displayed equation? If so, does it have its own equation number? Please advise.

Ideally yes, it is indeed an inline equation. If it is not easily achieveable with an inline equation, then also a displayed equation  is fine --but without equation number.

You can set these labels manually in the following way:

Extract the original \label-making capability from amsmath as it overrides/ignores \labels within an unnumbered equation environment (like \[...\]).

Step the equation counter and then print the label (using \textup{(\theequation)}) in a similar way to how \eqref prints the label.



\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\ltxlabel\ltx@label % Access to original LaTeX \label within equations
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\[
  \varphi = f \bigl(
    \overbrace{g(\dots)}^{\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\ltxlabel{eq:gdots}},
    \overbrace{h(\dots)}^{\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\ltxlabel{eq:hdots}}
  \bigr),
\]
where~\eqref{eq:gdots} represents something and~\eqref{eq:hdots} highlights something else. And, for reference,
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c \label{eq:quadratic}
\end{equation}
shows the quadratric equation for $f(x)$ in~\eqref{eq:quadratic}.

\end{document}

If you're using a non-default tag representation (default is (x) with the number x between parentheses), then some more work is required to make a better user interface that will match the typical output; add:
\newcommand{\printtag}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{#1}}}

between the \makeatletter...\makeatother pair and then use \printtag{\theequation} instead of \textup{(\theequation)}.

For subterm labelling within a numbered equation environment, the following setup works; defining a subterm counter, updating its representation and wrapping everything up in a \subtermeqlabel{<label>} macro:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\ltxlabel\ltx@label % Access to original LaTeX \label within equations
\newcounter{subterm}[equation]% Define a new counter, reset with every equation
\renewcommand{\thesubterm}{\theequation\alph{subterm}}% New subterm counter is \theequation with alphabetic subterm numbering suffix
\newcommand{\subtermeqlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subterm}\textup{\tagform@{\thesubterm}}\ltxlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
  \varphi = f \bigl(
   \overbrace{g(\dots)}^{\subtermeqlabel{eq:gdots}},
    \overbrace{h(\dots)}^{\subtermeqlabel{eq:hdots}}
  \bigr),
\end{equation}
where~\eqref{eq:gdots} represents something and~\eqref{eq:hdots} highlights something else. And, for reference,
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c \label{eq:quadratic}
\end{equation}
shows the quadratric equation for $f(x)$ in~\eqref{eq:quadratic}.

\end{document}

More work is needed to use the above within an align, as the environment content is processed multiple times with counter stepping happening differently to the normal equation.

+1. Are the \textup wrappers needed, though?

@Mico: Probably not; I'm following the guidance from \eqref, which is often used outside of a math environment, and therefore could be subject to font shape changes. \textup also prints sub-/superscripts in their appropriate sizes.

Thank you!
How would it change the code to use them in a displayed numbered equation?
Something like equation (X) with labeled subterms (Xa) and (Xb)

@ScaccoMatto: See the updated answer.

Hi, I noticed that this breaks when I load the hyperref package:
! Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }.

\par
l.22 where~\eqref{eq:gdots}
represents something and~\eqref{eq:hdots} highli...

(this happens only with "old" texlive version, I think <2022)

@ScaccoMatto: True. I'm unable to replicate the problem loading hyperref last using TeX Live 2024.

Something like this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \overbrace and \eqref macros
\newcommand\eqbox[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{7} % just for this example

\dots\  
$\varphi=f[\,
   {\overbrace{g(\dots)}^{\eqbox{eq:g}}}, 
   {\overbrace{h(\dots)}^{\eqbox{eq:h}}}\,]$ 
\dots

\medskip

Cross-references to items \eqref{eq:g} and \eqref{eq:h}.

\end{document}


Works great with inline math. If we try to reproduce the same example with display math instead, I obtained an error "! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:g' will be lost."

@gpr1 - This code should be used only with unnumbered displayed equations. If you have a question about numbered equations, please post a new query.

this error also occurs with unnumbered displayed equations in display math, as obtained with, for instance, "[ (equation) ]" or "$$ (equation) $$".

@gpr1 - I retract my earlier comment.
